# creating dynamic variables

Tags: c++, macros, user-input

Yes, I know dynamic variables aren't possible in c++. What I'm looking for is a workaround.

The idea is basically this. I've got a bunch of mathematical models together. They all have the exact same form, except for

1. the mathematical definition of a few functions
2. the needed constants: what they're called, their number, and their values.

The values of the constants may change between experiments, but everything else is a property of the material model itself. The constant parameters of the model are given in the input file in the form

`variable_A=2.0`

The material models (including all functions) were previously made through generated code, generated from abstract mathematical expressions through Maple, with a nice GUI environment to boot. This is now sadly broken, for multiple reasons. As a result of some other work, the models are now all the exact same in code, except for where they differ in their formal description. Instead of having a whole separate program to generate this code (which is currently broken and what we used to have), I'm looking for a simpler alternative, since now I only need roughly 20 lines throughout a given file to differentiate one material from another. However, the users who would implement these models aren't expected to have any knowledge of c++. So while I could simply ask them to go through the file and change things in various places, I was looking for something a little more user-friendly: so the user can just change a few lines *in one place* and define their model that way, without having to look through the rest of the code.

The functions to be defined by the user look like this.

```
double myfunction(double arg1, double arg2, vector arg3 ) \\just an example
{
    ...
    ...
    double a=database.find_constant("a_const");
    double b=database.find_constant("b_const");
    return sqrt(a*3+pow(b,2)-a/b)+...; \\still example pseudocode
}
```

The top ellipses are fairly ugly (not bad code, just syntax heavy and irrelevant), and so I don't want the end user to have to deal with them. My problem can probably be better described through examples:

My original plan was to use macros (yes, I know, the *horror*) at the top, so that this could become something like

```
 #define A database.find_constant("a_const")
 #define FUNCTION pow(A-2,3)   
 ...
double myfunction(...)
{
    ...
    return FUNCTION;
}
```

but then I found out that you can't nest macros. Which in retrospect is obvious, but I digress. Then I realized that I could just change the `#define A` statement to make `A` a global variable. Then i hit myself for even considering global variables. Basically, all my attempts to stick this all in one place where the user doesn't need much knowledge of c++ are ridiculous and/or horribly insecure.

Normally i hate asking such open ended questions, but I *really* don't want to give myself headaches. I'll only be working on this project for a short time, so designing a UI of some form and/or generating the code isn't practical. I'm going for 'proof of concept' at the moment.

Is there a better way to do this than having them go through the model and change the needed lines in the functions directly?

EDIT: I didn't write this whole project, nor was it originally intended to work in this way. The original tool we had for producing these files used Maple's code generation, where the functions and variables were entered as Maple syntax in a nice GUI. Unfortunately the GUI doesn't seem to work (consistently) anymore, and the code Maple returned stopped producing the right results once we switched versions: we're not sure what the problem is exactly, and we're just exploring other avenues right now. The new files are also *much* more similar than the previous ones (as a result of other work), which is part of the motivation for a new technique. I was hoping that I could get around code generation if I only needed a few lines to work together in a simple way. This isn't a "fix it for me!"  question, I'd just like to get a handle on what those other options might be. Yes I know it's not a good situation to begin with, and if this was planned from the start it would not be done this way. But this setup will probably be temporary, and as I said is more of a proof of concept than anything else.

Hopefully the question is clearer now. My issue is specifically with grouping everything in one place in a simple to use manner. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You want us to tell you how to magically replace ellipsis with code? Your question is way too abstract/vague IMO, this reads like an X=Y problem; how about showing some _real_ code that you would like to improve instead of `...` nonsense.

Comment: @ildjarn no, the ellipses are where code already exists that is irrelevant to the problem. It's largely some stuff with an automatic differentiation package that the user doesn't need to see. I'm not asking for explicit code. I don't have a method for this at all right now (beyond just getting the user to stick it in the functions directly, which I don't consider much of a 'method'), since I'm not familiar with the deep corners of c++. It seems like something that should have a clever solution, but I don't know enough to pinpoint what that solution might be.

Comment: @Robert it's really hard to understand your question.  Can you clarify how it works now, and wy that is unsatisfactory?  I almost think you want a 'std::map<std::string, double>', which can be used as a bunch of dynamic variables.

Comment: @MooingDuck I've rewritten the question; hopefully it's clearer now. I have no problem accessing constants, but I'd rather not have the user write out `dataset.find_constant("constant_name")` every time they needed one: it would be very awkward to read and work with. So what I'm looking for is a way to define both the in-code names for the constants, and the formulas in the same place. The dataset is unfortunately passed around entirely through function arguments, rather than being a property of the material class, so I think I may indeed have to change that to something like a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you can try that 'acts' like macros but isn't, is to encapsulate the various function groups in anonymous structs:

```
struct
{
    double find_constant(const char* s) { do-stuff...; }
    double calc_value(int a, int b) { do-stuff...; }
    ...
} GeneralStuff;
```

Use a macro to access the functions in this struct:

`#define DoStuff GeneralStuff`

and in your code access it:

```
...
DoStuff.find_constant("a_const");
...
```

If a user needs to change the code, he makes a copy of the struct, apply the changes, and 
redefines the macro:

```
struct
{
    ...changed code...
} MyStuff;

#define DoStuff MyStuff
```

These would be the only changes needed, if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The variables themselves can actually be handled pretty easily: read in the values and put them into a `std::map<std::string, double>` (or, `int` instead of `double` if the values are all integers). For example:

```
std::map<std::string, double> values;

// Code to read name and value from the file goes here.
// Then something like:
values[name] = value;
```

The rest -- evaluating expressions, is a rather deeper subject. Code for it is pretty easy to find though (e.g., [muParser](http://muparser.sourceforge.net/)). I'd guess most have a support variables on their own so you probably won't need to write an explicit map of your own though.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is just to get them to write the expression in the input file, then parse it yourself and look up any unknown references from database, then evaluate it. If you don't need very high evaluation performance, this is relatively simple for both you and them. You can use, for example, Lua to quite easily perform this naturally- all you'd have to do is set the `__index` metatable value on the global table to look up into the database, and voila- all database constants are "global" Lua values.

Answer (score 0):

This may just cause more headaches, but for future stuff like this maybe consider using boost.spirit to build an actual parser, or maybe proto to build a domain-specific language.

Answer (score 0):

(1) If you want users to see and edit minimal code, you might consider abusing the preprocessor, by splitting the code into the bit before the math (BEGIN_ROBERTS_MAGIC.inl) and the code after the math (END_ROBERTS_MAGIC.inl)

BEGIN_ROBERTS_MAGIC.inl  (your code)

```
#include <cmath>
...otherstuff
double function(*args go here*)
{
    ....prep work
    //this file ends right before the lines with the math
```

END_ROBERTS_MAGIC.inl  (your code)

```
    //this file begins right after the lines with the math
}
...otherstuff
```

STUPID_PHYSICS_MODEL.cpp  (their code)

```
#include "BEGIN_ROBERTS_MAGIC.inl"

double a=database.find_constant("a_const"); //or double a = constant["a"];
double b=database.find_constant("b_const"); //or double b = constant["b"];

return sqrt(a*3+pow(b,2)-a/b)+...;

#include "END_ROBERTS_MAGIC.inl
```

This means that the file that the other people see is only five or so lines of code, that looks really straightforward and not at all intimidating, with all the magic hidden in some other files they don't see.

(2) As others suggested, you could put the user's code into scripts that are not part of the C++ code (via spirit, lua, javascript, or any other scripting language) which would mean you sont have to recompile for each model, and also you can add or remove actual global variables at run time, but this is a more complicated.